# Opening a new workspace in Xcode 4

Tags: xcode4

I've found that if I close the default workspace window in Xcode, if I try to open any new files (including by selecting New Window), they all open up as editors, without the full functionality of the workspace window.  How can I open a new workspace similar to the one that is created by default when you open a project in Xcode?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm pretty sure what you're looking for is:

View menu --> Show Tool Bar

Is that the secret?

---

A follow up tip: you often want **Show Utilities**. Particularly when you bring up an interface builder editing session. Cheers!

Comment: Close enough, I was looking for Show Tool Bar.  That was really silly of me- sorry, I'm just not used to XCode 4.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open Xcode 4
2. Go to menubar > File > New > New Workspace...
3. Drag in files to edit to the left pane of the Xcode window
4. Click the file in the left pane
5. Start editing! :)